# Convert a JPEG image to SVG in Apache Batik

Tags: maven, svg, jpeg, batik

I'm new to Apache Batik and want to convert the JPEG image to SVG image using transcoder https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/using/transcoder.html.

Here is my code:

```
public void saveAsSvg() throws Exception {

        SVGTranscoder t = new SVGTranscoder();

        t.addTranscodingHint(SVGTranscoder.KEY_FORMAT, true);

        String svgURI = new File(inputFilePath).toURL().toString();

        InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(inputFilePath);
        Reader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
        TranscoderInput input = new TranscoderInput(inputStreamReader);

        OutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream(outputFilePath);
        Writer outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(ostream);
        TranscoderOutput output = new TranscoderOutput(outputStreamWriter);

        t.transcode(input, output);

        ostream.flush();
        ostream.close();
        System.exit(0);
    }
```

My pom.xml is according to [Convert a SVG image to a JPEG image using Apache Batik](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37899651/convert-a-svg-image-to-a-jpeg-image-using-apache-batik/37900107?noredirect=1#comment63272652_37900107):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
    <artifactId>batik-transcoder</artifactId>
    <version>1.7</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
    <artifactId>batik-codec</artifactId>
    <version>1.7</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
    <artifactId>xmlgraphics-commons</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

The exception I'm getting is stated below:

```
org.apache.batik.transcoder.TranscoderException: element
    at org.apache.batik.transcoder.svg2svg.PrettyPrinter.fatalError(PrettyPrinter.java:1750) ~[batik-transcoder-1.7.jar:1.7+r608262]
    at org.apache.batik.transcoder.svg2svg.PrettyPrinter.print(PrettyPrinter.java:253) ~[batik-transcoder-1.7.jar:1.7+r608262]
    at org.apache.batik.transcoder.svg2svg.SVGTranscoder.prettyPrint(SVGTranscoder.java:230) ~[batik-transcoder-1.7.jar:1.7+r608262]
    at org.apache.batik.transcoder.svg2svg.SVGTranscoder.transcode(SVGTranscoder.java:186) ~[batik-transcoder-1.7.jar:1.7+r608262]
    at com.example.SaveAsJpeg.saveAsSvg(SaveAsJpeg.java:80) ~[classes/:na]
```

.......

Couldn't learn anything out of the exception I'm getting. Please help.

Comment: Batik works the other way round, it's an SVG to JPEG converter. It does not support what you want to do and I expect it never will.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Step 1
ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon(imagePath);
Image imageTmp = imageIcon.getImage();
//Step 2
BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(imageIcon.getIconWidth(), 
imageIcon.getIconHeight(),
BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

bufferedImage.getGraphics().drawImage(imageTmp, 0, 0, null);
//step 3
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "png", baos);
byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray();
String imageEncode = "data:image/png;base64," + Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(bytes);
baos.close();
bufferedImage.flush();

//step 4
Element image = document.createElementNS(SVGDOMImplementation.SVG_NAMESPACE_URI, "image");
//set X,Y,Width,Height ...
image.setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink", "xlink:href", imageEncode);
```

You can convert image to svg image element by using encode base64.

1. Read image to ImageIcon object
2. Create BuffredImage from ImageIcon
3. Convert BuffredImage to encode Base64.
4. Put image encode into **<xlink:href>** tag